# Working Word Counter, but problem with commas and periods

Tags: javascript, split

I have a small program to display how many times a word is repeated in a paragraph, but I can't split the commas and periods for some reason. So the script sees `'Cola'`, `'Cola,'` and `'Cola.'` as different words.

How can I ignore the punctuation?

```
<script>
    function count() {
        var inputVal = document.getElementById("textInput").value; //get text to count
        var storyWords = inputVal.split(' '); // split words

        var filterWords = storyWords.map(function(x) {
            return x.toLowerCase()
        });
        filterWords.sort();

        var current = null;
        var cnt = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < filterWords.length; i++) {
            if (filterWords[i] != current) {
                if (cnt > 1) {
                    //    var h = document.getElementById('fillIn');
                    var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
                    var row = table.insertRow(1);
                    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                    cell1.innerHTML = current;
                    cell2.innerHTML = cnt;

                    var h = document.createElement("LI");
                    var t = document.createTextNode(current + ' // --> ' + cnt + ' times');
                    h.appendChild(t);
                    document.body.appendChild(h);

                }
                current = filterWords[i];
                cnt = 1;
            } else {
                cnt++;
            }
        }

        if (cnt > 1) {

            var h = document.createElement("LI");
            //var h = document.getElementById('fillIn');
            var t = document.createTextNode(current + ' // --> ' + cnt + ' times');
            h.appendChild(t);
            document.body.appendChild(h);
        }

        document.getElementById("clickMe").disabled = true;
    }

    // On button click, execute the function
    document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = function() {
        count();
    }
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change this:

```
var storyWords = inputVal.split(' '); // split words
```

By:

```
var storyWords = inputVal.toLowerCase().match(/\w+/g); // split words
```

Please notice that we are converting the whole string to lower case, so you may get rid:

```
var filterWords = storyWords.map(function(x) {
     return x.toLowerCase()
});
```

and directly do the sort:

```
storyWords.sort();
```

Note:

> \w+ Matches any alphanumeric character including the underscore.
>   Equivalent to [A-Za-z0-9_].

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!

Yes, I converted to lower case because JavaScript thinks 'Cola' and 'cola' are two different words!
Ohh, I see!! Got you!!!  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

replace

```
var storyWords = inputVal.split(' '); // split words
```

to

```
var storyWords = inputVal.split(/[ ,.]/);
```

Comment: `/[ ,.]+/` to avoid empty strings

Answer (score 0):

Modify your function just a little and you are done. 
Before instead of directly checking for filterWords[i], remove all the punctuations from it by using replace()

**var word = filterWords[i].replace(".", "").replace(",", "").replace("!", "");**

> New function will be like:-

```
<script>
    function count() {
        var inputVal = document.getElementById("textInput").value; //get text to count
        var storyWords = inputVal.split(' '); // split words

        var filterWords = storyWords.map(function(x) {
            return x.toLowerCase()
        });
        filterWords.sort();

        var current = null;
        var cnt = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < filterWords.length; i++) {
        var word = filterWords[i].replace(".", "").replace(",", "").replace("!", "");
        if (word != current) {
                if (cnt > 1) {
                    //    var h = document.getElementById('fillIn');
                    var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
                    var row = table.insertRow(1);
                    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                    cell1.innerHTML = current;
                    cell2.innerHTML = cnt;

                    var h = document.createElement("LI");
                    var t = document.createTextNode(current + ' // --> ' + cnt + ' times');
                    h.appendChild(t);
                    document.body.appendChild(h);

                }
                current = filterWords[i];
                cnt = 1;
            } else {
                cnt++;
            }
        }

        if (cnt > 1) {

            var h = document.createElement("LI");
            //var h = document.getElementById('fillIn');
            var t = document.createTextNode(current + ' // --> ' + cnt + ' times');
            h.appendChild(t);
            document.body.appendChild(h);
        }

        document.getElementById("clickMe").disabled = true;
    }

    // On button click, execute the function
    document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = function() {
        count();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `getWordCnt` returns an array with nested key/value pairs, where the *unique* key represents a word and the value states the amount of the word's appearances:

```
function getWordCnt(text) {
  return Object.entries(            // converts an object to an array of [key, value] pairs
    text
      .toLowerCase()
      .split(/\W+/)                 // splits the text where it matches the regexp
      .filter(line => !!line)       // removes elements with empty strings (the last element here)
      .reduce((acc, el) => {        // returns an object which represents word:count pairs
        acc[el] = acc[el] + 1 || 1
        return acc
      }, {})
  )
}

let text = "Hello World, hello Sun!"
const words=getWordCnt(text) // [ [ "hello", 2 ], [ "world", 1 ], [ "sun", 1 ] ]
```

You can manipulate it further through **destructuring**, like for example:

```
const strings = words.map(
  ([key, value]) => `The word '${key}' appears ${value} time(s)`
)
console.log(strings)  // [ "The word 'hello' appears 2 time(s)", "The word 'world' appears 1 time(s)", "The word 'sun' appears 1 time(s)" ]
```

Comment: Could you explain your code instead of just posting it without any comment and explanation?